# How to encrypt certain fields in managed packages

Tags: encryption, shield, data-protection-and-privacy

are there alternatives to encrypting personally identifiable data in fields that are not encrypt able through Shield?

Comment: Your own encryption/decryption scheme on read/write with your own keys stored in e.g. custom metadata. All reads/writes will have to go through your custom code.